# Should Raspberry Pi Zero in USB ethernet mode respond to DHCPDISCOVER request?

Tags: pi-zero, dhcp

I have set up my Raspberry Pi Zero to work as ethernet gadget, by editing /boot/cmdline.txt and config.txt. I also added the SSH file. But my Linux machine is refusing to connect to Raspberry Pi Zero over USB ethernet connection.
In:

```
journalctl -fu NetworkManager
```

I see that my Linux is sending DHCPDISCOVER like this:

```
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s20f0u1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s20f0u1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s20f0u1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s20f0u1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 18
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s20f0u1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 21
```

Should Raspberry Pi Zero be responding to this DHCP request?

(Because it is not, it fails with request times out)

Comment: No DHCP, it uses Zero Configuration Network, 169.x.x.x IP. Just ssh to raspberrypi.local

Comment: Well yeah if that worked, that would be no problem, but it doesn't. However, that should be an answer, since my original question was if Raspberry Pi Zero should respond to DHCP request, which is, as I see, false.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing things a little - its the client (for eg. your Raspberry) thats **SENDS** the discover packets, and its DHCP server's role to **RESPOND** to such packets.

If you have no DHCP server listening at your LAN, than after some time, your devices may fallback to [Zeroconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking) addresses (169.254.0.0/16) and [Multicast DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS) (".local" suffix).

Comment: Are you sure you understand my setup? My Pi is supposed to act like an internet gadget, like a network adapter. Therefore it would make sense for Pi to host the DHCP server since from the point of view of the PC, Pi is the new network and it wants to get IP from that network.

Comment: @MaushicaOrihara the DHCPDISCOVER packets you are seeing are logged at machine thats is client to DHCP, so if its on your Pi, than that Pi tries to contact server.